# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo ... java.lang.IllegalStateException: RequestQueue not initialized

Tags: java, android

I am using a library in my package which shows images from  Flickr I declared it in the manifest file but it still gives the error

```
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity    ComponentInfo{com.examples.youtubeapidemo/com.mani.staggeredview.demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RequestQueue not initialized
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RequestQueue not initialized
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at com.mani.staggeredview.demo.app.StaggeredDemoApplication.getRequestQueue(StaggeredDemoApplication.java:35)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at com.mani.staggeredview.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-12 22:00:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15128):    ... 11 more
06-12 22:00:07.452: I/Process(15128): Sending signal. PID: 15128 SIG: 9
```

declared in manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mani.staggeredview.demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="Activity from library">

    </activity>
```

in class from where I am calling it

```
import  com.mani.staggeredview.demo.*;
.
.
.
.
btn_naat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),com.mani.staggeredview.demo.MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);  
        }

    });
```

Comment: from which class you are calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you are using the `Volley` library for networking. It seems you haven't initialized your `RequestQueue` object:

```
if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Add the above code wherever you have declared your `RequestQueue` object. Try this. It should work.